# Trying to Populate ViewModel List from Linq query MVC "List doesn't contain definiton for ..."error"

Tags: model-view-controller, viewmodel

I am (trying to) build a multiple choice test application that will pass a list of multiple choice questions (select lists) from the controller to a view.
Then populate the view using a foreach loop, post the answers back to the controller, check them and increment the score for each correct answer and then update the db.

I am trying to populate the view model list using a Linq query (to keep my controller thin, I am doing this via a method in my Service layer).

Models

```
Questions (db first)

namespace AccessEsol.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Question
{
    public Question()
    {
        this.ExamDets = new HashSet<ExamDet>();
    }

    public int QuID { get; set; }
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
    public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    public string Foil1 { get; set; }
    public string Foil2 { get; set; }
    public string Foil3 { get; set; }
    public string Level_ { get; set; }
    public string GrammarPoint { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ExamDet> ExamDets { get; set; }
}
}
```

Exam

```
namespace AccessEsol.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Exam
{
    public Exam()
    {
        this.Candidates = new HashSet<Candidate>();
        this.ExamDets = new HashSet<ExamDet>();
    }

    public int ExamID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public int AdminID { get; set; }
    public string StartLevel { get; set; }

    public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExamDet> ExamDets { get; set; }
}
}
```

There is also a model for Candidate that contains the CandID:

And the view model that uses these models:

```
namespace AccessEsol.Models
{
public class ExamQuestionsViewModel
{
    public int QuID { get; set; }
    public int CandID { get; set; }
    public int ExamId { get; set;  }
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
    public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    public string Foil1 { get; set; }
    public string Foil2 { get; set; }
    public string Foil3 { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string GrammarPoint { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ExamDet> ExamDets { get; set; }

}
}
```

This is the method that is to populate the view model:

```
        public static List<ExamQuestionsViewModel> AddQuestions()
    {

        AccessEsolDataEntities db = new AccessEsolDataEntities();

        string questionLevel = GetLevel(); 
        int currentCand = GetCandID();
        int currentExam = GetExamID(); 

        //model = new DataAccess().Populate();
        var qu = (from a in  db.Questions
                 where a.Level_ == questionLevel
                 select a).ToList(); 

    List<ExamQuestionsViewModel> exam = new List<ExamQuestionsViewModel>();


        foreach (var IDs in exam)
        {

            currentCand = exam.CandID;
            currentExam = exam.ExamId;

        }


      return (exam);
    }
```

The error message I am getting is

```
'System.Collections.Generic.List<AccessEsol.Models.ExamQuestionsViewModel>'
does not contain a definition for 'ExamId' and no extension method 
'ExamId' accepting a first argument of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.List<AccessEsol.Models.ExamQuestionsViewModel>'      could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
 reference?
```

What am I doing wrong here? All feedback much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this instead of your foreach:

```
foreach (var IDs in exam)
{    
    currentCand = IDs.CandID;
    currentExam = IDs.ExamId;    
}
```